# Single Stateless Servlet in Spring Maven App

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets

I have one spring maven application,

I want to add a new servlet, I have added that, but I need that servlet to be stateless,

i.e. example, its a simple servlet which souts hello, but user needs to be login for that,

if user is not logged in then it redirects to login page which is offcourse due to session validation,

so my question is can we exclude one particular servlet from session check?? is it possible? if yes then how?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you want to achieve. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: And post your code relevant to this servlet and its configuration. Is it spring mvc?

Answer (score 1):

Just add new servlet mapping url to your exclusion urls which does not need session validation. As per your question login.jsp must be configured as it does not require authentication token to present in session, add new servlet url to this configuration